# Does the Hashtable implement every method in the Map interface?

Tags: java, hashtable

Since a class that implements an interface in Java must define every method in the interface to avoid being declared as abstract, I was wondering about the following:

When I create a program that instantiates a Hashtable object, why am I not required to define every method in the Map interface? Are the methods I do not explicitly define, created automatically as "stubs"?

Comment: Sorry, but I think you loosing something very important here. When you're instantinating an object, you **not** implementing anything. You just creating an object, **which is** `Map` (**which is** implementing it's methods).

Comment: As a side note, Hashtable is obsolete and you should prefer HashMap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating an object from `Hashtable` class which already implemented all necessary methods.You are not creating a class, but an object from that class.
If you created a class which implements `Map`, the compiler would ask you to implement all the necessary methods.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the Hashtable implement every method in the Map interface?

Yes. If you take a look at the JavaDoc the [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) class has been defined as

```
public class Hashtable<K,V>
extends Dictionary<K,V>
implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

Notice, that the class has **not** been declared *abstract* and it *implements Map*. Hence, it must and it does implement all the methods defined in `Map` interface.

> When I create a program that instantiates a Hashtable object, why am I not required to define every method in the Map interface?

When you instantiate an object, the implementation of its methods is provided by its class. So, when you instantiate a `Hashtable` object, it uses the implementation already provided by the `Hastable` class.

The need for providing an implementation comes when you're creating a class ***not*** when instantiating an object from it. At instantiation the class must not be abstract i.e. the implementation should already be present; either provided by you or like in the case of `Hashtable` by the JDK.